# UniFi Dream Machine Special Edition (UDM SE) - iptables NAT PREROUTING not working on own subnet

Tags: networking, dns, iptables

This is a very confusing situation for me and I feel like there isn't an answer to this. But I'm at a loss after hours of testing, figuring out how things are currently working or not working as I would expect. If you're brave enough to read this post, thank you in advance.

Gateway 192.168.1.1 (UDM SE)

DNS server resides on 192.168.1.2

Initial Firewall Rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.4-192.168.4.254 -j MASQUERADE
```

This works great. It forces anyone doing a DNS request like 'nslookup site.tld 8.8.8.8' to get a response from 192.168.1.2 instead of 8.8.8.8 on all 4 subnets. This is the expected and desired result. For reasons I won't bore you with I need to change things around and discovered unexpected and unwanted results.

Change One Delta (Post Routing Range):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.2.1-192.168.4.254 -j MASQUERADE
```

With this configuration devices on the 192.168.1.x subnet can 'nslookup site.tld 192.168.1.2' but will timeout on 'nslookup site.tld 8.8.8.8'. The other three subnets ( 192.168.2.1-192.168.4.1 ) get results from 192.168.1.2 doing lookups either way. If I delete the 2 PREROUTING entries, 'nslookup site.tld 8.8.8.8' resolves from 8.8.8.8 with no timeout on the 192.168.1.x devices and again on the other 3 subnets. Why is the MASQUERADE rule required in order for the 192.168.1.x devices to resolve when the PREROUTING rules were present?

Change Two Delta (DNAT --to)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.123
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.123
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.4-192.168.4.254 -j MASQUERADE
```

Doing an 'nslookup welcome.opends.com 192.168.1.2' or 'nslookup welcome.opends.com 8.8.8.8' from the three subnets ( 192.168.2.1-192.168.4.1 ) gives me the expected results of using 208.7.222.123 as the DNS and correctly returns 146.112.59.8. From the 192.168.1.x devices 'nslookup welcome.opends.com 8.8.8.8' returns 146.112.59.8 as I would expect because of the PREROUTING rules. However, doing a 'nslookup welcome.opends.com 192.168.1.2' returns 146.112.59.9 meaning that the query went through 192.168.1.2 instead of 208.67.222.123 as defined by the PREROUTING rules. Why aren't these 192.168.1.x devices getting pre-routed regardless of the DNS server specified during nslookup? Clearly they get intercepted when using 8.8.8.8 with nslookup.

Thank you for looking at this monster post.

Answer (score 0):

> With this configuration devices on the 192.168.1.x subnet can 'nslookup site.tld 192.168.1.2' but will timeout on 'nslookup site.tld 8.8.8.8'. The other three subnets ( 192.168.2.1-192.168.4.1 ) get results from 192.168.1.2 doing lookups either way. If I delete the 2 PREROUTING entries, 'nslookup site.tld 8.8.8.8' resolves from 8.8.8.8 with no timeout on the 192.168.1.x devices and again on the other 3 subnets. Why is the MASQUERADE rule required in order for the 192.168.1.x devices to resolve when the PREROUTING rules were present?

Because same-subnet communications bypass the router.

Your local DNS server (192.168.1.2) knows that the client device (192.168.1.x) is in the same subnet (this is literally the purpose of the "subnet mask" parameter!), so it will send the response directly to the client's MAC rather than the router's MAC, allowing your Ethernet switch to deliver it straight to the destination.

As a result of that, the UDM will not get any chance to apply reverse NAT to the response, and therefore the client receives the response from a completely different IP address than it has sent the query to and just ignores it.

The usual workarounds are a) not putting your servers in the "client" subnet to begin with, or b) "NAT hairpin" using SNAT/MASQUERADE to hide the original source IP address, as you're currently doing, or c) Proxy-ARP together with Ethernet-level "port isolation" (sometimes also called "private VLAN"; equivalent to Wi-Fi "client isolation") to trick all subnet devices into resolving even local IP addresses to the router's MAC address.

> However, doing a 'nslookup welcome.opends.com 192.168.1.2' returns 146.112.59.9 meaning that the query went through 192.168.1.2 instead of 208.67.222.123 as defined by the PREROUTING rules. Why aren't these 192.168.1.x devices getting pre-routed regardless of the DNS server specified during nslookup? Clearly they get intercepted when using 8.8.8.8 with nslookup.

Same as above: same-subnet communications bypass the router. Your client device knows that 192.168.1.2 is in its own subnet, so it will send the query directly to 192.168.1.2's MAC address instead of the router's MAC address, meaning that the router will have no chance to apply any NAT or firewall rules to the packet.

The SNAT/MASQUERADE method will not work here, but the other two workarounds are still applicable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll stop trying to fix something that ain't broke. I'll put the DNS on a different subnet than everything else as my ultimate solution.

Something I'm still confused about, is if the devices bypass the router that are on the same subnet, then why does the first configuration force everything to go through 192.168.1.2 for its DNS? It would seem MASQUERADE is indeed working. In short, what does the original configuration work but not "Delta Two" work pointing to another --to IP.?

Comment: The first configuration works because the _original_ destination IP address of the packets is not local (it's 8.8.8.8 in your `nslookup xyz 8.8.8.8` example), so the packets will be sent through the router where they can be intercepted and DNATed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not understanding. Let me try again and thank you for your patience.
Comparing these two rules: 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
from the 192.168.1.x subnet:  nslookup xyz 8.8.8.8 enforces DNS 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 208.67.222.123
from the 192.168.1.x subnet: nslookup xyz 8.8.8.8 allows the 8.8.8.8 dns request and does NOT enforce 208.67.222.123
Why?
Side note: the 192.168.2.1-192.168.4.1 subnets are forced to use 208.67.222.123 as their DNS.